# FileDialog.Filter Property show all except a specific format

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want to have a filter in `FileDialog.Filter` Property in a way that it shows all file endings except the ones I want. Is this possible?

Comment: Why you need to do that?

Comment: I believe you would need to make your own, as the filter is a white list not an exclude.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? Or do you have any example of such custom thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**, it is not possible.

*-- Edit --*

Long answer: **No**, it is not possible because format of this property is predefined (and checked) as described in comments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx), if you are on WinFroms).

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer and I don't think it's wrong, but it's hardly what I would call a high quality answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, it's ok, I just want to know, how can I improve its quality then? I realy don't know what to add:\

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but it would be nice to explain why it is not possible.